# Aptana Studio 3 keeps adding .pydevproject file, how can I disable Python?

Tags: python, aptana, aptana3

Aptana Studio 3 keeps adding .pydevproject file, how can I disable Python or whatever it's doing this

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally somehow set the project as PyDev project. To disable, right click on the project > PyDev > Remove PyDev Project Config